# Why is this set an event?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

As a part of a setup for another problem, my text remarks that it can be used without a proof that if $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are random variables then $$C:=\{ \omega\in\Omega \ | \ \sum X_n(\omega) \ \text{converges} \}$$ is an event.

It's somewhat unusual to see such statements (that something "can be used without a proof"). So I assumed that the proof is beyond the scope of my course. Yet I'm quite curious to see why.

I have tried to construct $C$ from sets known to be events yet to no avail. Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

We can say :$$\omega \in C  \Leftrightarrow (\forall m \in \Bbb N )(\exists p \in \Bbb N)( \forall k \geq p) \quad \left|\sum_{i=k+1}^{+\infty} X_k(\omega)\right| < \frac 1{m+1}  $$
That gives:$$C=\bigcap_{m \in \Bbb N}\bigcup_{p \in \Bbb N}\bigcap_{k \geq p} Y_{m,p,k}$$
Where : 
$$Y_{m,p,k}=\left\{\omega \in \Omega / \left| \sum_{i=k+1}^{+\infty} X_k(\omega) \right| < \frac 1{m+1}\right\}$$

Comment: Many thanks! The $+\infty$ in $Y_{m,p,k}$ doesn't allow me to apply the theorems I have at my disposal (and show that $Y$ itself is an event). Can we apply Cauchy criteria, then (following your reasoning): $$ \omega \in C  \Leftrightarrow \forall m\in \mathbb N \ \ \exists n\in \mathbb N \ \ \forall i,j \geq n: \left| \sum_{k=i+1}^j X_k(ω)\right|<\frac{1}{m}$$ then $$C=\bigcap_{m \in \Bbb N}\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N}\bigcap_{i \geq n}\bigcap_{j \geq n} Y_{m,p,i,j}$$ with $$Y_{m,p,i,j}=\left\{\omega \in \Omega \ : \ \left| \sum_{k=i+1}^{j} X_k(\omega) \right| < \frac 1{m}\right\}$$ Correct?

Comment: this is awesome and better than my answer. This provided space tag is complete (for example finite dimesion one).